# What is a purpose of mOffset in OpenGL ES projection calculations?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I know the theory of `glFrustumf` and `glOrthof` but I'm quite
puzzled by the fact that there is another parameter in android
[method that sets projection](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/opengl/Matrix#orthoM%28kotlin.FloatArray%2C+kotlin.Int%2C+kotlin.Float%2C+kotlin.Float%2C+kotlin.Float%2C+kotlin.Float%2C+kotlin.Float%2C+kotlin.Float%29) which is `mOffset` which does not exist in normal [OpenGL implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/OpenGL/glortho).``

```
public static void orthoM(float[] m, int mOffset,            <---- mOffset
        float left, float right, float bottom, float top,
        float near, float far)
```

In the implementation it seems that this `mOffset` parameter shifts matrix index by the value that is setted:

```
    m[mOffset + 0] = x;
    m[mOffset + 5] = y;
    m[mOffset +10] = z;
    m[mOffset +12] = tx;
    m[mOffset +13] = ty;
    m[mOffset +14] = tz;
    m[mOffset +15] = 1.0f;
    m[mOffset + 1] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 2] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 3] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 4] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 6] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 7] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 8] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 9] = 0.0f;
    m[mOffset + 11] = 0.0f;
```

Can anyone please explain why would you ever need to offset matrix index for the projection? What is a purpouse of `mOffset`?

Comment: @httpdigest Ohhhhhhh right! You are probably right! Very nice thinking!

Comment: I come from python world so this was out of my thinking scope box. :)